# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload not be raised in Console app

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5

I have an assembly that when accessed spins up a single thread to process items placed on a queue. In that assembly I attach a handler to the DomainUnload event:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_DomainUnload);`

That handler joins the thread to the main thread so that all items on the queue can complete processing before the application terminates.

The problem that I am experiencing is that the DomainUnload event is not getting fired when the console application terminates. Any ideas why this would be?

Using .NET 3.5 and C#

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately for you, this event is not raised in the default AppDomain, only in app domains created within the default one.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload%28VS.90%29.aspx):

> This event is never raised in the
>   default application domain.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to subscribe the event for the specific domain.  You also can't rely on the domain get unloaded at termination time.  Remove the comment from this code to see that:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test");
        ad.DomainUnload += ad_DomainUnload;
        //AppDomain.Unload(ad);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void ad_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("unloaded, press Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple `AppDomain`s (and thus the `AppDomain.DomainUnload` event) was removed with .Net core. `AppDomain.DomainUnload` will never be triggered.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0024 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=net-8.0#remarks:

> On .NET Core, the `AppDomain` implementation is limited by design and does not provide isolation, unloading, or security boundaries. For .NET Core, there is exactly one `AppDomain`. Isolation and unloading are provided through [`AssemblyLoadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=net-8.0). Security boundaries should be provided by process boundaries and appropriate remoting techniques.