# How to initialize and de-initialize only one time during application life cycle in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one static class that I need to initialize some code during the class used for the first time and de initializes when the application process dies. Actually, the init method calls the native C++ apis using the PInvoke method. I know I can use static constructor but now I need to call a native de-init method at the end,

```
public static class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        MyInitFirstTime();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the application life cycles in the Global.asax file [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178473(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: You don't have any control over `static` constructor... I think you might get better help if you explain what you are trying to achieve and what it is that you want to release/deinitialize. This question might be the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @HoomanBahreini needs to call a native function on the app start and when app finished in other words on the creation of process and on the exit of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a static class, you can use the Application_Start and Application_End "special methods" as [documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods
>   that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once
>   for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each
>   HttpApplication instance.

Another option is to overwrite the [HttpApplication.Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.dispose?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpApplication_Dispose) or the [Disposed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.disposed?view=netframework-4.8). If you decide to overwrite Dispose(), don't forget to invoke the base class Dispose() method.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any native method for static classes, but you can use AppDomain `DomainUnload` event instead:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("dummy").DomainUnload += CurrentDomain_DomainUnload;

        MyInitFirstTime();
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_DomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Free resources
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also found the ProcessExit function so which one is more accurate?

Comment: @user960567 : Definitely `DomainUnload`. Unlike `DomainUnload`, `ProcessExit` event is timed! means CLR let 2 second per appdomain to run `ProcessExit` handlers before terminating application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693160/appdomain-currentdomain-domainunload-not-be-raised-in-console-app

Comment: @user960567 : Right! But also the main point still remains. `ProcessExit` is timed and there isn't any guarantee to finished before application being terminated! (answer is updated to cover issue you're pointed. not best, but at least works)